# How to compiler knows it is wrong

Tags: scala

I have following function:

```
def apply[A,B](fa: Option[A])(ff: Option[A => B]): Option[B] = (fa, ff) match {
  case (None, _) => None
  case (Some(_), None) => None
  case (Some(a), Some(f)) => Some(f(a))
}
```

and it compiles fine.

But when I gonna change the function as follow:

```
def apply[A,B](fa: Option[A])(ff: Option[A => B]): Option[B] = (fa, ff) match {
  case (None, _) => None
  case (Some(_), None) => Some("Hello")
  case (Some(a), Some(f)) => Some(f(a))
}
```

The compiler complains the function does not conform type `Option[B]`.

If I would pass to the apply function `Some(1)` and return `Some("Hello")`, I would get another type then the input, then in my opinion it returns another type then the input type.

How does the compiler knows, that the value type does not conform `Option[B]` and why `None` conform `Option[B]` in the first example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1st - `None` is a valid value for all `Option[]` types. In other words...

```
val optx: Option[X] = None
```

...is valid for any type `X`.

2nd - What does the compiler know about `B`? `ff`, if it is not `None`, will produce an output of type `B`, and the output of this `apply()` method must be of the same type, i.e. `B`, but wrapped in an `Option`.

`Some("Hello")`, i.e. `Option[String]`, does not conform to `Option[B]` because the compiler has not been told that `ff` is constrained to produce only `String` output.

Answer (score 1):

Because `None` is a subtype of `Option[Nothing]`. And `Nothing` is a subtype of everything. And `Option` is covariant in it's type param, so `Option[Nothing]` is a subtype of `Option[B]` (whatever `B` is).

So, the first compiles because  `None` is a subtype of `Option[B]`.
The second fails to compile because `Option[String]` is not a subtype of `Option[B]` (maybe it is at call-time, but the compiler won't know that).